# Breakpoint inside template function, Eclipse CDT Kepler

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I know this question may have been asked before, however I did not find any satisfactory answer. My problem is the following: I am developing `C++` under Eclispe CDT Kepler. I use `g++4.8.2` as the compiler and `ggdb 7.6` as the debugger (both installed via `macports`), so not the `clang` tools that come with OS X (my OS is OS X Mavericks).

Now, in Eclipse I am able to set breakpoints and do a step-by-step debugging everywhere EXCEPT in template functions (breakpoint inside template functions are just ignored). The template functions are defined in implementation files (.cpp extension), and are standalone functions, not members of any class. I also set up `qt creator` with `ggdb` as debugging tool, and get the same behaviour, breakpoints are ignored inside template functions, and get the following warning (only when trying to add breakpoints in template functions):

```
&"warning: GDB: Failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not supported on socket\n"
```

So, it must be a `ggdb` problem.

Apple's default `llvm` works, but I must use `g++` because of its `OpenMP` support, and can not use `llvm` in combination with `g++`.

Did you bump into such annoying behaviour? Is this a known issue with `ggdb`? And are you aware of any solutions to this problem, i.e. how to set up breakpoints in template functions when compiling with `g++`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall a specific bug in this area in gdb 7.6.

Normally if this kind of problem arises it is due to missing debuginfo -- a compiler problem, not a debugger problem.  However, there isn't enough information here to really know.

When I have a problem like this I normally use objdump to view the debuginfo and search for the function I'm interested in.

Comment: It works fine in other OS-es, it's just a OS X problem I believe. Even in a terminal session, the "step" command in "gdb" does not step into a function if the function is templated... Everything works fine in Linux/Solaris though...

Comment: My `gdb` was installed through `macports`, will try to compile `gdb` from source from GNU. Thanks for the answer though!